# get the path of serial file in any Android device

Tags: android, tablet

I have tried finding the path for serial key of the sdcard and usb , but unable to find the path for the same in karbonn tablet st10.

I have code to read the serial number of the sdcard , the below code is what I am using , but for karbon tablet st10 I am unable to find the path of the serial file path from the file explorer.

My question what code should I write to get the path of serial file in any Android device

```
String sd_cid = "";
            String memBlk = "";
            try {
                ///*
                File file = new File("/sys/block/mmcblk2");
                if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory()) {

                    memBlk = "mmcblk2";
                } 
                else
                    {
                    File file1 = new File("/sys/block/mmcblk1");
                        if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory()) {
                        memBlk = "mmcblk1";
                        }
                        else {
                            //System.out.println("not a directory");
                            memBlk = "mmcblk0";
                        }
                    }
            String str2="/sys/block/"+memBlk+"/device/serial";
            sd_cid= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(str2)).readLine();
         return sd_cid;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```